# Why does the search code work on its own but not when added to rest of code?

Tags: c++, string, find

I'm working on a C++ project that requires a client to send a file path and search string to a server. The server then searches through the provided file for the search string and prints the whole line for each instance it finds the search string. Searching in its own program works fine, however, when I add it to the rest of my code it does not work.
Search on its own is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
 std::ifstream inFile;
 std::string path = argv[1];//"dat/anna_karenina.txt";
 inFile.open(path);
 std::string searchStr = argv[2];//"you m";
 std::string line = "";
 int bytesSent = 0;
 if(inFile.is_open()) {
  while(std::getline(inFile, line)) {
   if(line.find(searchStr, 0)!=std::string::npos) {
    char sending[line.length()];
    for(int i=0; i<line.length(); i++) {
     sending[i]=line.at(i);
    }
    std::cout << line << std::endl;
    bytesSent += line.length();
   }
  }
 }
 std::cout << "BYTES SENT: " << bytesSent << std::endl;
 inFile.close();
 return 1;
}
```

When I run this all lines are printed how they should be.
This is my server code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sys/sysinfo.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
 if(argc != 2) {
  std::cout << "Need domain socket file name" << std::endl;
  exit(-1);
 }
 struct sockaddr_un server;

 char buffer[32];
 unlink(argv[1]);

 int serverSock = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
 if(serverSock < 0) {
  perror("socket");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
 }

 std::cout << "SERVER CONNECTED" << std::endl;
 size_t maxClients = get_nprocs_conf()-1;

 memset(&server, 0, sizeof(server));
 server.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
 strncpy(server.sun_path, argv[1], sizeof(server.sun_path)-1);

 int success = bind(serverSock, (const struct sockaddr *) &server,
                 sizeof(struct sockaddr_un));
 if(success < 0) {
  perror("bind");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
 }

 success = listen(serverSock, maxClients);
 if(success < 0) {
  perror("listen");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
 }

 while(true) {
  std::cout << "Waiting for clients" << std::endl;
  int clientSock = accept(serverSock, nullptr, nullptr);
  if(clientSock < 0) {
   perror("accept");
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  std::cout << "CLIENT CONNECTED" << std::endl;

  std::string path="";
  std::string searchStr="";
  char fileBuff[32];
  char searchBuff[32];

  memset(fileBuff, 0, 32);
  success = read(clientSock, fileBuff, 32);
  if(success < 0) {
   perror("read");
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  for(int i=0; i<(sizeof(fileBuff)/sizeof(char)); i++) {
   path+=fileBuff[i];
  }
  std::cout << path << std::endl;
  if(path.empty()) {
    std::cout << "No path to file given" << std::endl;
    exit(1);
  }

  memset(searchBuff, 0, 32);
  success = read(clientSock, searchBuff, 32);
  if(success < 0) {
   perror("read");
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }


  for(int j=0; j<(sizeof(searchBuff)/sizeof(char)); j++) {
   searchStr+=searchBuff[j];
  }
  std::cout << searchStr << std::endl;

  if(searchStr.empty()) {
   std::cout << "No search string given" << std::endl;
   exit(1);
  }

  std::ifstream inFile;
  inFile.open(path);
  std::string line = "";
  int bytesSent = 0;
  if(inFile.is_open()) {
   //std::cout << "ok" << std::endl;
   std::cout << searchStr << std::endl;
   while(std::getline(inFile, line)) {
   // std::cout << "ok" << std::endl;
    if(line.find(searchStr, 0)!=std::string::npos) {
     /std::cout << "ok" << std::endl;
     char sending[line.length()];
     //memset(sending, 0, sizeof(sending)/sizeof(char));
     for(int k=0; k<(sizeof(sending)/sizeof(char)); k++) {
      /std::cout << "ok" << std::endl;
      sending[k]=line.at(k);
     }
     std::cout << line << std::endl;
     bytesSent += line.length();
    }
   }
  }
  std::cout << "BYTES SENT: " << bytesSent << std::endl;
  inFile.close();
  close(clientSock);
 }
 return 1;
}
```

When I run the server and client code, the client does as it should, and so does the server, until `if(line.find(searchStr, 0)!=std::string::npos) {` at which it acts as if the search string is not found anywhere on any line and prints no lines and says the bytes sent is 0. I don't understand why the server cannot search for the string but the search method on its own can. I fairly sure the search string is correct; when I print it out it is what it needs to be. I'm just confused as to what I'm doing wrong in the server code for it to not enter the if statement.

If you're confused as to what bytes sent is, the server is supposed to send all the lines found to the client for it to print and count how many bytes it's sending. I don't need the server to print the lines. I am just doing it now so I can see that the lines are actually being found.

Comment: `char sending[line.length()];` -- Note that this is not valid C++.  Arrays in C++ must have their size denoted by a compile-time constant, not a runtime value.  Instead, use `std::vector<char> sending(line.length());`

Comment: You always copy exactly 32 characters into `searchStr`, regardless of how many characters the client actually sent. So you aren't searching for `"you m"` but for `"you m"` followed by a bunch of `'\0'` characters. Apparently, and unsurprisingly, this sequence of 32 characters doesn't appear in any line of your file.

Comment: Let's say `searchBuf` contains "Hello" followed by a bunch of zeroes. `for(int j=0; j<(sizeof(searchBuff)/sizeof(char)); j++) { searchStr+=searchBuff[j]; }` adds "Hello" followed by a bunch of zeroes to `searchStr`. When you try to find it in a file you're searching for a string with a bunch of zeroes after it, not just the alphanumeric characters. Try printing its `size()` after you assign the data to it. If you know the buffer is 0 terminated then `searchStr = searchBuff` is the right way to assign just the string data to your string. https://godbolt.org/z/E19T6c86f

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thanks, I don't code in c++ consistently, so I forgot about arrays. It worked!

Comment: @RetiredNinja Thank you! That explanation and Igor's helped me understand it better and now it works!